composition of flows of linearly independent, commuting vector fields is injective
Let $M$ be n-dim manifold and $X_1,...,X_k$ k linear independent and mutually commutative ($[X_i,X_j]=0\forall i\ne j$) vector fields. Let $\varphi_t^i$ be the flows (one parameter diffeomorphism) near a point $p\in M$ of vector field $X_i$. In a little neighbourhood $V$ of $0\in\mathbb{R}^k$, define the map
$$
\varphi:V\to M, \varphi(t_1,...,t_k)= \varphi_{t_1}^1\circ\varphi_{t_2}^2\circ\cdots\circ\varphi_{t_k}^k (p)
$$
I want to show that $\varphi$ is an embedding in a neighborhood $U$ of $0$. I have shown that the differential is everywhere injetive, and I need to show that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism in a proper $U$. It is obviously continuous as composition of diffeomorphisms, and my idea is to show that $\varphi$ is injective in $U$, and then restrict its codomain to $\varphi(U)$ so that it is bijective.
But I'm stucked with the injectivity of $\varphi$. For example if we only have two flows $\varphi_t^1$ and $\varphi_t^2$. Then let $\varphi_{t_1}^1\circ\varphi_{t_2}^2 (p)=\varphi_{t_1'}^1\circ\varphi_{t_2'}(p)$, then I get
$$
\varphi_{t_1-t_1'}^1=\varphi_{t_2-t_2'}^2
$$
I want to conclude that the above equation implies $t_1-t_1'=0$ and $t_2-t_2'=0$. I know since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are linear independent, the flows at $p$ should go to different directions and not intersect in a little intervall. But I don't know how to translate this intuition to proof. Also, this methode seems not easy to generalize to k flows.

I might be missing something, but it’s not obvious to me that this assignment is continuous. Each flow is essentially some smooth map $\phi:I\times M\rightarrow M$, such that for any $t\in I$ the restriction to ${t}\times M$ is a diffeomorphism. How is it then immediate that the assignment  $(t_1,\dots,t_k)\mapsto \phi^1(t_1,\phi^2(t_2(\dots(\phi^k(t_k,p))))$ is continuous?

I guess you just need to prove injectivity for some very small neighbourhood of 0. If you want to argue by contradiction, you should assume that the injectivity is violated for every small t, right? It seems to me then that taking a derivative that would give you some identity that contradicts the fact that the vector fields are linearly independent. Hope this helps!

This is a local statement. Given your commuting relation, the easiest would be to take a chart where $X_i=(\partial/\partial x^i)$. In those coordinates, it is almost immediate.

@Chris for fixed p, is it just the composition of smooth maps, so it's also smooth?

Thank you all but I've found a brief answer which hold very general: For a smooth map $f: M\to N$ with injective differential at some point $p\in M$, then on a neighborhood $U$ of $p$, the restriction $f|_U$ is an embedding. These are Theorem 4.25 and Proposition 4.1 in the book Smooth Manifolds by John Lee.
